# Visual Studio for Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (or higher) on Windows Vista (x86)? I already installed Visual Studio 2010 Express, but I need a higher version to build android apps with it.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you even tried to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633858/can-visualstudio-2015-be-installed-on-windows-vista

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533807/can-visualstudio-2013-be-installed-on-windows-vista?rq=1

Comment: "but I need a higher version to build android apps with it." - You will have VS2015 and higher on a Windows 7 or higher machine in that case.  VS2015 was the first version where the community edition was fully functional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No

Only up to 2010

> As of Visual Studio 2012, Microsoft has limited compatibility to Windows 7 or higher. If you want to run Visual Studio on a Vista operating system, you will need Visual Studio 2010 or 2008.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533807/can-visualstudio-2013-be-installed-on-windows-vista